# how to resolve closing error in certain section of my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, while-loop, richtextbox, exit

I am using C#, when running my code it works fine until you click the red X top right(close). It only happens when this part of the program runs and you click the x, other times, when you click the x no problem.

The the following error occur:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'RichTextBox'.'
```

it only happens in this section of the code

```
while (firstColorChange < lines.Length + numTextLength.Value)
        {
            if (firstColorChange < lines.Length)
            {
                tbDisplayText.Select(firstColorChange, 1);
                tbDisplayText.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
                firstColorChange++;

            }
            
            if (firstColorChange > numTextLength.Value)
            {
                tbDisplayText.Select(secondColorChange, 1);
                tbDisplayText.SelectionColor = Color.White;
                secondColorChange++;
            }

            await Task.Delay(speed);
            if(secondColorChange == lines.Length)
            {
                tbDisplayText.Clear();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Where is that code located? It's probably in an event handler that gets executed as the form and its controls are being disposed. Think about the logic and make sure that you don't use a control that might already be disposed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also see [ask] and [mre].

Comment: You do not need to do anything in the Form_Closing event unless you want to abort the exit.  `Application.Exit()` is certainly not needed

Comment: just make sure that you are not running an infinite while loop. if it is not required

Comment: @jmcilhinney this code is in a button click event, the user would choose a couple of drop down items, and based on that, the code needs to run until it reaches the end of lines[].
If it runs to the end of lines[] it then does not generate the error if I click the close X

Comment: How long does that section of code generally take to execute?

Comment: You may solve this with a `CancellationTokenSource` and its token. Cancel the source when the form/window gets disposed and use the token on the `Task.Delay` call or simply check the token after `Task.Delay` if cancellation is requested and if exit the method

Answer (score 0):

Do you provide complete error information?